# what possible are the possible reasons the sorting of my objects is different when deploying to heroku than what it is locally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, heroku

i deploy doing:

git add .
git commit -a -m "Next release"

git push heroku master

and also for the db
heroku db:push

without getting any errors.
Am i missing something?

Comment: do you use hash to sort objects?

Comment: I have this in my controller:

@products = Product.scoped.order("sorting")

sorting is just an integer property of object product

Answer (score 1):

It might be good to note the stack your are using on heroku.

```
>heroku stack
```

If your sort is using hashes, Ruby 1.8.7 will not sort the hashes in the same order unlike ruby 1.9.2.

Comment: aspen-mri-1.8.6
* bamboo-ree-1.8.7
  bamboo-mri-1.9.2

Comment: It seems you are on 1.8.7 note the asterisk(*) so hashes will not be sorted in any order. Are you on ruby 1.9.2 locally?

Comment: no i am on 1.8.7  Should i upgrade to 1.9.2 and change also to the corresponding stack?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the odds favor different collations on the two platforms. In SQL databases, sort order is controlled by a collation (aka "collation order" or "collating sequence").

But I'd expect `ORDER BY` to sort integers the same.  Of course, if you develop against SQLite and deploy to PostgreSQL, you might find differences in the handling of nulls and duplicates.

See [SQLite documentation sections](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) 5.0 Sorting, Grouping and Compound SELECTs, and 6.0 Collating Sequences.

Some of the details with respect to PostgreSQL are documented under [CREATE TABLE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdatabase.html).